# how to access to router from adsl modem

Tags: networking, router, internet

i have been setting up network at my work.
there is a adsl modem that is connected to switch for spread internet and also all pcs are connected to each other throw switch.
there is a second router that is connected to switch via wan port and two pc is connected to that router wirely.
from those pcs i can access default gateway of adsl modem and router and networking and internet. but from those that are connected directly to switch, i cant access router gateway and pcs ip that connected to router.
default lan gateway of first group pcs:
192.168.1.1
default lan gateway of second router:
192.168.0.1
default gateway of second router wan port:
192.168.1.1
here is diagram i have created:

[image]

Comment: Does the connection go from the switch to the router's WAN or LAN port? If WAN, try LAN.

Comment: @harrymc yea i use of wan . i need more information about setting up gateway. if i use of lan instead of wan i think internet will not share to router and pcs connected to that

Comment: Easy to try, but I think with LAN everything will be on the same network segment.